# Multiplying .val() x 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to multiply the val() in this function by 2. It's not outputting though.
Where is my code mixed up?

```
$('.retina-outline').text($('.billboard-height').val() *2 + 'PX');
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof $('.billboard-height').val())` output?

Comment: Try `parseFloat( $('.billboard-height').text() ) * 2`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte string undefined

Comment: There you go. :) You can't multiply `undefined`.

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/CqGH9/

Comment: @DreamEater that function doesn't make sense...based on the code in my Q

Comment: @MikeBarwick What type of field is it? `input`, `div`, `anchor`, `li`?

Comment: Then use `parseFloat( $('.billboard-height').val() ) * 2`

Comment: @Mike, are you definitely sure your `.billboard-height` class selector *only* matches `<input>` elements?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Absolutely!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var h = $('.billboard-height').val() *2 ;
$('.retina-outline').text(h.tostring() + 'PX');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pixels = (parseInt($('.billboard-height').val()) * 2) + 'PX';
$('.retina-outline').text(pixels);
```

Comment: This is not working...

Comment: Could you be a little more specific or create a Fiddle that includes the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

`$('.billboard-height').val()` may be something like `20px` and `$('.billboard-height').val() * 2` is `NaN`.

You should use `parseInt($('.billboard-height').val()) * 2` in which `parseInt` will change `20px` into `20`.

Comment: my `$('.billboard-height').val()' is just a numeric value...

Comment: `+('10px') * 2 === NaN`. Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: @MikeBarwick It's not numeric, it's `undefined`...

Comment: `+"20px"` will not convert it into number. `parseInt("20px", 10)` will.